# sed write a line in a certain way

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I have this text file that have lines made in a certain format just like this next line

```
bla bla name1=WORD1 bla    bla name2=WORD2 bla bla name3=WORD2
```

I want to extract WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 without all the bla bla and printing them with semicolon

```
WORD1;WORD2;WORD3
```

can this be done using only sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `WORD*` always occur in this manner, you can use these two patterns `[^=]*=` and `[^ ]*` to match before and the word respectively. `^` at the beginning of a group inverts the matching. Something like this works in GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/[^=]*=([^ ]*)[^=]*=([^ ]*)[^=]*=(.*)/\1;\2;\3/' infile
```

Comment: Yes, it assumes `WORD*` comes after an equals sign, if others are present, this method fails.

Comment: I have an idea but I dont know the syntax in sed ; how to inverse substitute in sed ? I mean to substitute I use sed 's/word1//g' but I want the inverse , to subituite anything except word1 , how to do it ?

Comment: it worked , but it failed when I used or ,  sed 's/.*\\(word1\|word2\\).*/\1/' why ?

Comment: It only matches `\(word1\|word2\)` once, if you want to match both use this construct `s/.*\(word1\).*\(word2\).*/\1;\2/` or if you run `sed` with `-r` `s:.*(word1).*(word2).*:\1;\2:`.

Answer (score 2):

One way that handles a different `key=value` string.

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
bla bla name1=WORD1 bla   noname=WORD4 bla name2=WORD2 bla bla name3=WORD3
```

And `script.sed` with content:

```
## Add a newline character just before each word.
s/name[1-3]=\([^ ]*\)/\n\1/g;

## Remove all characters until each newline appended in previous command, so only
## words will be left, and insert a ';' between them.
s/[^\n]*\n\([^ ]*\)/\1;/g;

## Remove last ';'.
s/;[ ]*$//;
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

That yields:

```
WORD1;WORD2;WORD3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interseted in awk, below would work.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\=/){split($i,a,"=");if(p){p=p";"a[2]}else{p=a[2]}}}}END{print p}'
```

tested below:

```
> echo "bla bla name1=WORD1 bla    bla name2=WORD2 bla bla name3=WORD2" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\=/){split($i,a,"=");if(p){p=p";"a[2]}else{p=a[2]}}}}END{print p}'
WORD1;WORD2;WORD2
>
```

Comment: If you have installed awk in windows.it should work.I have tested in Solaris unix.Also please tag it for windows.